# Ruby Hash comparison match number and string

Tags: json, ruby, hash, xml-parsing, comparison

How do you compare two hashes and count values as equal if they are equal as strings (250 == "250")?

For example, I want these hashes to be considered equal:

```
hash1 = {a: "3", b: "2"}
hash2 = {a: 3, b: 2}
```

The hashes come from an XML parser which is returning hashes with string values.

Comment: Can you provide a sample for input and output?

Comment: Please put the information into your question, formatted appropriately. Please don't use "edit" or "update" tags because we can tell what changed. When asking it's important to show what you tried. We are happy to help fix your code, but asking us to write the code for you doesn't go over well. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)”.

Comment: The input is the 2 hashes in the example above. Then we do something to compare them and output `1` because they are equal, even though "3" == 3 gives `0`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to transform the hash that has string values into a hash with integer values, then compare. If you are using Ruby 2.1 or greater, you can map directly from hash1 and create a new hash from the result:

```
new_hash = hash1.map { |k, v| [k, v.to_i] }.to_h
new_hash == hash2 ? 1 : 0
=> 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but what if we don't have only int values, for example:
{                                                      {
    a => "3",                                          b => 3.14,
    b => "3.14",      to be equal to         c => "foo",
    c => "foo"                                        a => 3
}                                                      }

What will happen when map tries to convert foo and 3,14 to int?

Comment: {
 a => "3",
b => "3.14",c => "foo"
}`

Comment: This site is utter shit... How do you edit comments?????
Thank you for the answer but what if we don't have only int values, for example: 
`{
    a => "3",
    b => "3.14",
    c => "foo"
}`
To be equal to:
`{
    b => 3.14,
    c => "foo",
    a => 3
}`
What will happen when map tries to convert foo and 3,14 to int?

Comment: It's a bit unusual to have integers, floats, and strings mixed into the same hash. I'd suggest at a minimum that you be consistent about your Fixnums, either using integers or floats but not both. If you use `new_hash = hash1.map { |k, v| [k, v =~ /[^\d\.]/ ? v : v.to_f] }.to_h` you'll get close to what you want.